# How to get all the reference assemblies in Xamarin.Android project in C#

Tags: c#

We need to get all the reference assemblies in **Xamarin.Android** project. We have used the **GetEntryAssembly()** to get all the reference assemblies as below.

```
var referenceAssemblies = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

But these methods are not supported in Xamarin.Android. Provide any suggestions to get the reference assemblies in Xamarin.Android project?